# #REF! Error on tabs starting with Letter C Followed by numbers and then letters again

Tags: excel

When building an excel spreadsheet I am using a tab that starts with C then has 3 numbers and then some letters, for some reason indirect will not correctly reference these tabs.

Example:

Tab named: C850AA

On my summary tab I am using this formula

=INDIRECT($A10&"!$A$5")

and Cell A5 is: C850AA

It gives a #REF! error as a result for Cell A10 when there is a number of 5 in that cell

If I change to any other letter of the alphabet it works. B850AA is just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sheet name is in A5, and the cell you want the value of is in A10 on C850AA, then the below formula should work

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!"&"A10")
```

Comment: Works great, any reason why mine does work for letters other than C?

Answer (score 2):

See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx

> **Learn about syntax rules for names**   The following is a list of syntax rules that you need to be aware of when you create and edit
>   names.  Valid characters    The first character of a name must be a
>   letter, an underscore character (_), or a backslash (). Remaining
>   characters in the name can be letters, numbers, periods, and
>   underscore characters.
>   **Note**   You cannot use the uppercase and lowercase characters "C", "c", "R", or "r" as a defined name, because they are all used as a
>   shorthand for selecting a row or column for the currently selected
>   cell when you enter them in a Name or Go To text box.

Seems like without the quotes around the sheet name you might be running into this.  With no quotes Excel may assume the sheet name is a range name, and try to evaluate it.

I tested a sheet name beginning with "R" and that had the same problem as "C".